# How do I get text to wrap next to an image instead of beneath it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using twitter bootstrap and also it's responsive design.  When I shrink my browser (Chrome) or view the below code in my iPhone browser, the text all appears on one line.  However, when I increase the font size to 20px, the text wraps underneath the image.  What can I do in order to have the the text (when it is 2 lines long) appear to the right of the icon/image instead of wrapping beneath it?

```
            <div class = 'row'>
                <img src = "http://a286.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/113/Purple2/v4/a2/b1/40/a2b14050-c4be-4243-2cad-7dc1fcaec726/mzl.vkophohs.png" style = "width:60px;">
                   <span style = "font-size:18px;">The Hobbit: Kingdoms of Middle-earth<br /></span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the same as Nik but a bit differently:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkxz4/

```
<div class = 'row'>
<div class="col_image">    
<img src = "http://a286.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/113/Purple2/v4/a2/b1/40/a2b14050-c4be-4243-2cad-7dc1fcaec726/mzl.vkophohs.png" style = "width:60px;">
</div>
<div class="col_text">The Hobbit: Kingdoms of Middle-earth</div>
</div>

.row { width:400px; overflow:hidden; }
.col_image { float:left; width:60px; margin:0 20px 0 0; }
.col_text {float:left; width:320px; font-size:18px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<img src="http://a286.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/113/Purple2/v4/a2/b1/40/a2b14050-c4be-4243-2cad-7dc1fcaec726/mzl.vkophohs.png" style="width:60px;float:left;">
<div style="float:left;">The Hobbit: Kingdoms of Middle-earth<br/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = 'row'>
 <img src = "http://a286.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/113/Purple2/v4/a2/b1/40/a2b14050-c4be-4243-2cad-7dc1fcaec726/mzl.vkophohs.png" style = "width:60px; float:left; padding-bottom:30px;">
<span style = "font-size:20px; vertical-align:middle; line-height: 30px; ">The Hobbit: Kingdoms of Middle-earth<br /></span>
</div>
```